# Send multipart post to glassfish(payara) fail if using Certificate authentication

Tags: rest, apache-httpclient-4.x, glassfish-4, client-certificates, payara

We have Rest web services on a glassfish4 (payara) server
Our rest client is based on httpClient Lib
As Authentication we use certificate and basic auth. 
The client work well getting and posting infos to WS
But when we send a multipart post with file bigger than few bytes, parsing the request hang until a timeout

If we disable the certification auth, all is working

Comment: If you don't get an answer in reasonable time, try creating an issue on Payara tracker: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to payara blog, we address the problem: we needed to change a configuration in payara,  "Max Save Post Size" in Network Config->Network Listener -> http-listener-2 (the one using ssl) - http tab